# Team City Build Branches on Checkin

Tags: build, teamcity

I am working on setting up a new build server using Team City 2017.2.

Our source control (TFS 2015) is structured like this:

- Trunk
- Branches

  - Branch1

    - DEV
    - UAT
  - Branch2

    - DEV
    - UAT
- etc...

I have setup a build that is working using a vs root pointed at a specific DEV branch and Trunk.

Each new project gets its own branch that I create in TFS at the project's start. Coding takes place DEV. We want to setup the Team City build so that it automatically will build the branch that has a check in. A build.proj file is what controls what code the build server builds in the branch.

We are trying to avoid having to manually maintain a seprate VSC roots and builds for each branch as branches are created and merged to trunk/deleted as projects are completed.

I am having trouble figuring out if this is possible and if so how to do it. Can someone point me in the right direction on this?

Thanks in advance,
-Wayne